# PyQt - How to turn on/off spellcheck highlighting

Tags: python, pyqt, spell-checking

I have a button which sets/unsets spellcheck highlighting in a QTextEdit box (ref [PyQt - How to turn on/off spellchecking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722061/pyqt-how-to-turn-on-off-spellchecking)) which works fine.

Then I added a language selection QComboBox and tied its signal to the button's property but its highlighting set/unset doesn't work on changing the language. It drives me nuts, there may be something small and stupid I've done, but for the sake of it I can't find anything wrong with it.

The button (action rather) is

```
self.actionSpellCheck = QAction(QIcon(self.icon_spellcheck),
            "Auto &Spellcheck", self,
            shortcut=Qt.CTRL + Qt.SHIFT + Qt.Key_O,
            triggered=self.spellcheck, checkable=True)
```

The combobox is

```
self.cb_lang = QComboBox(tb)
    tb.addWidget(self.cb_lang)
    lang_list = self.dict_broker.list_languages()
    self.cb_lang.addItems(lang_list)
    self.cb_lang.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.spellcheck)
```

and the self.spellcheck is

```
def spellcheck(self):
    pos = self.cursor.position()
    if self.actionSpellCheck.isChecked():
        lang = self.cb_lang.currentText()
        self.dict = self.dict_broker.request_dict(lang)
        self.highlighter.setDict(self.dict)
        self.setHighlighterEnabled(True)
        self.show_status("Spellcheck language is set to " + self.dict.tag, None)
    else:
        self.setHighlighterEnabled(False)
        self.highlighter.setDict(None)
        self.show_status("Spellcheck is turned off", None)
    self.cursor.setPosition(pos, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)
    self.textEdit.setTextCursor(self.cursor)
    self.textEdit.setFocus()
```

How come the highlighter gets set/unset on clicking the button, but nothing happens on selecting the language (it only happens after I start typing, not immediately on combobox selection)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `HighLighter.setDict` method, you'lll see that it doesn't do much other than reassign the `dict` attribute.

Also, the `SpellTextEdit.setHighlighterEnabled` only resets the document.

So you're going to need a method to re-highlight the text whenever the `dict` changes. Fortunately, `HighLighter` is a subclass of `QSyntaxHighlighter`, which already has a [`rehighlight`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#rehighlight) slot which does what is required.

So you just need to amend your `spellcheck` method as follows:

```
def spellcheck(self):
    pos = self.cursor.position()
    if self.actionSpellCheck.isChecked():
        self.setHighlighterEnabled(True)
        lang = self.cb_lang.currentText()
        self.dict = self.dict_broker.request_dict(lang)
        self.highlighter.setDict(self.dict)
        self.highlighter.rehighlight()
    else:
        ...
```

Comment: I'll try that. But as I said, it works fine even without rehighlight() when I press the button. I don't understand why the combobox change doesn't work if it uses exactly the same method?

Comment: Yes, it works now when I change language in the combobox. Thank you very much.